# macOS: backupd creates hidden empty folder on desktop

Tags: time-machine, desktop, macos

I noticed a hidden empty folder on my desktop, `.J5NASODWVY73`, created and last opened 2012-03-16. I have full permissions and I can trash it, but after every restart / reboot, the folder reappears, date unchanged. This happens as part of the boot process and before Time Machine attempts a run.

My system runs macOS 10.14.6

---

The actual output of *fs_usage* as demanded by benwiggy

```
Last login: Sun Apr  2 19:22:03 on ttys000
MacPro:~ xxx$ sudo fs_usage | grep /.J5NASODWVY73
Password:
19:52:35  fsgetpath         /Users/xxx/Desktop/.J5NASODWVY73      0.000009   Finder      
19:52:35  fsgetpath         /Users/xxx/Desktop/.J5NASODWVY73      0.000009   Finder      
19:52:35  getattrlist       /Users/xxx/Desktop/.J5NASODWVY73      0.000010   Finder      
19:52:35  fsgetpath         /Users/xxx/Desktop/.J5NASODWVY73      0.000007   Finder      
19:52:35  access_extended   /Users/xxx/Desktop/.J5NASODWVY73      0.000018   Finder
...
20:43:43  fsgetpath         /Users/xxx/Desktop/.J5NASODWVY73      0.000007   com.apple.Cl
20:43:43  fsgetpath         /Users/xxx/Desktop/.J5NASODWVY73      0.000007   com.apple.Cl
20:43:43  fsgetpath         /Users/xxx/Desktop/.J5NASODWVY73      0.000007   com.apple.Cl
20:43:43  getattrlist       /Users/xxx/Desktop/.J5NASODWVY73  
...
21:30:14  fsgetpath         /Users/xxx/Desktop/.J5NASODWVY73      0.000009   TinkerTool S
21:30:14  getattrlist       /Users/xxx/Desktop/.J5NASODWVY73      0.000009   TinkerTool S
21:30:14  fsgetpath         /Users/xxx/Desktop/.J5NASODWVY73      0.000007   TinkerTool S
21:30:14  getattrlist       /Users/xxx/Desktop/.J5NASODWVY73      0.000006   TinkerTool S
```

Comment: @ bmike : thanks for the edit – much better this way!

Comment: Do you have TM backups going back to 2012? Are your TM backups completing without error? Have you run first aid on your system disk? What is the path -- at the root (as your command suggests), or on your user's Desktop? Can you provide the actual output of the `fs_usage` command? You're sure that backupd is *creating* the folder, not *reading* it?

Comment: @benwiggy my TM backups only go back to january 2023; the old 6 TB HDD got to small. the folder is hidden, and i only noticed it hitting <code>CMD</code> + <code>SHIFT</code> + <code>.</code> to find a file in my library. the hidden folder <code>.J5NASODWVY73</code> has no owner. i can delete it but it will come back after each reboot, *always* with a different date. the oldest so far was 2011, the most recent 2019. here is a ![valid XHTML] [screenshot] [screenshot]: https://bit.ly/42WOXwe of the information panel.

Comment: For future use, you can use "backtick" for "code" in comments, e.g., `code`  It's the key next to "1" on most US keyboards.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by brute force:

1. I installed macOS 10.14.6 from scratch and used a Time Machine backup to restore the data; that didn't change anything, the hidden folder persisted.
2. I replaced the TimeMachine volume with a fresh HDD and ran the latest `macOSUpdCombo10.14.6.pkg`over the boot volume, and shut down the Mac.
3. I booted from a recovery partition, ran First Aid from the Disk Utility app, and shut the Mac down again. I restarted and reset NVRAM with a deep garbage collection by holding <kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> for four chimes, started in Safe Mode (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>).
4. After the folder didn't show up after the Safe Mode boot, I rebooted normally.

The hidden folder has not resurfaced; so far, so good.